# AWS IAM: AssumeRole vs GetSessionToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to generate a temporary credentials access key and secret key. I've used `AssumeRole`. The description says it generates an access key and secret key. But `GetSessionTokenResult` can also generate an access key and secret key. Then what's the use of assumeRole?

```java
AWSSecurityTokenService awsSecurityTokenService = 
    AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder 
    .standard().withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
    .withRegion(region).build();
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
    .withRoleArn(
                 "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/p-27c229ade194_ec2")
    .withRoleSessionName("RedshiftSession");
AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = awsSecurityTokenService
    .assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);
GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
getSessionTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(1200);
GetSessionTokenResult getSessionTokenResult = awsSecurityTokenService
    .getSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = getSessionTokenResult.getCredentials();

final String adminAccessKeyId = sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId();
final String adminAccessSecretKey = sessionCredentials
    .getSecretAccessKey();
```

Earlier using assumeRole it showed error => `aws:iam::user/admin is not sts:assumeRole on resource role aws:iam::role/role_id`.
By adding `aws:iam::user/admin` in trusted relationship of `role_id` it worked.

If I will comment out `AccessRole` and its other called class. I can generate an access key and secret key. What's the purpose of using `AssumeRole`?

Answer (score 22):

There are [several methods to obtain temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html), depending upon your requirements:

- [GetSessionToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) gives you a set of temporary credentials **based on your own IAM User**. This is commonly used to activate Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA), or to create some scoped-down credentials for a situation where you want to limit access (eg giving access to an application that uploads/downloads data to S3, without giving any non-S3 access). The new credentials have, at most, the same permissions as you have (and never any more).
- [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) is used to obtain credentials that have a **totally different set of permissions**. For example, you might not have permission to access S3, but you might have permission to assume an "S3 access" role. The credentials returned then allow you to temporarily access S3. Another example is providing access to **administrator permissions** — rather than always using an account with Admin permissions, it is safer to **temporarily assume an Admin role**, do the admin activity, then return to using normal credentials. Less is likely to go wrong than always using Admin-level access.

Also, AssumeRole can be used to **gain cross-account access**. For example, a user in Account A could assume a role in Account B, which grants access to resources in Account B. This is not possible via GetSessionToken.

I always find this article useful to explain the differences: [Understanding the API Options for Securely Delegating Access to Your AWS Account | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/understanding-the-api-options-for-securely-delegating-access-to-your-aws-account/)

Comment: So to generate credentials in case of AssumeRole I will need to use AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient, so whose access key, secret key should I use to access this API, admin's or the user(s) to whom I want to give temporary access for resources.

Comment: You will _always_ need to use your own credentials to create the client, so that it can check whether you are allowed to make the call (for both AssumeRole and GetSessionToken). When you call AssumeRole, you will also need to provide the ARN of the role you wish to assume.

Comment: Okay, so that means no admin only user access key and secret key for AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient, one last query that if I'm using AssumeRole then do I have to provide trust-relationship of admin in the role. I mean in JSON of role. Because in above code snippet i had to provide

Comment: I think that the role needs to trust the assuming entity (eg IAM User) and the assuming entity also needs permission to call `AssumeRole`. Please try to follow the documentation and if you have further problems, create a new Question showing your code and explaining the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understand it. Both of them are solving different issues.

1. GetSessionToken - This is used to request temporary credentials for a user in untrusted environments. Typically, invoked by MFA-enabled users. The purpose of the sts:GetSessionToken operation is to authenticate the user using MFA. The user passes a MFA code in the invoke call, the response is {accessId, secretKey, sessionToken, expiry date}. This session token can now be used to access endpoints programmatically that require MFA authentication. You could also call this endpoint with AUTHPARAMS - this would be your signature.

Refrence : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html

2. AssumeRole - This is used to attach roles to a user temporarily. "The AssumeRole API operation is useful for allowing existing IAM users to access AWS resources that they don't already have access to." Like the example given by John above, suppose a user requires admin
   privileges once a month to update some ec2 instances. Instead of
   giving the user admin permissions day to day, the admin role can be
   assumed by the user temporarily when required. This would ensure
   less goes wrong. This works for cross account access too - the user
   can assume a role created in another account. Another example is, you want your developers to have temp access to production access role.